# Sampling through joint probability table

Tags: r, dataframe, simulation, generate

I'm trying to create a generated dataset through a joint probability table (for example 10% of the total dataset containing $10,000 salary and none for education). But also the distribution needs to include the probability from a second joint probability table

Table 1

| Education\Salary | $10,000 | $20,000 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| None | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| Hs | 0.3 | 0.1 |
| College | 0.2 | 0.1 |

Table 2

| Age\Salary | $10,000 | $20,000 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| 40 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| 50 | 0.2 | 0.2 |

I was able to simulate the dataset for table 1, but have no idea how to do it simultaneously with table 2.

Comment: To generate a sample with three variables (Age, Education, Salary) you need to know the full probabilty, that is, a three-way table unless educatio/age are independent variables.

Comment: Also, both your salary tables should have the same margin sums. i.e.  `colSums(table1) == colSums(table2)`. Given that it is not the case, there is something wrong...

Comment: All the variables are independent. Full probability is 1